# Mediascanner-extractor consuming all RAM in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ram, 16.04

I recently upgraded Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04. Now whenever I plug in my external hard disk, mediascanner-extractor starts consuming all my RAM and Swap space till my computer hangs and I have to force restart it.

[Screenshot Image Link Below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHS6E.png)

Answer (score 1):

I'm also running 16.04 and had a problem with this process just today. It wasn't smashing my RAM or swap, but `mediascanner-service-2.0` and `mediascanner-extractor-2.0` were preventing me from safely ejecting a USB drive with a lot of photos on it.

Attempts to `pskill` the processes were immediately followed by the process restarting and continuing to hammer the drive. I used `pstree` to see what was calling `mediascanner-service-2.0` and found that it was something called `upstart`, which was entirely unknown to me before this problem arose. With what little investigation I've done, I gleaned that `upstart` appears to be in charge of running various jobs and keeping them running.

I found the upstart configuration for `mediascanner-2.0` at:

```
/usr/share/upstart/sessions/mediascanner-2.0.conf
```

It contained the following:

```
description "Media Scanner"
author "James Henstridge <james.henstridge@canonical.com>"

start on started dbus

respawn
exec /usr/bin/mediascanner-service-2.0
```

Needless to say, the `respawn` command is apparently what instructs `upstart` to restart `mediascanner-service-2.0` (which calls `mediascanner-extractor-2.0`) whenever I killed it.

Someone in #ubuntu on irc.freenode.org gave me this solution:

```
echo manual > ~/.config/upstart/mediascanner-2.0.override
```

This will override the aforementioned configuration, telling upstart to ignore start and stop commands for `mediascanner-2.0`, leaving the program and its configuration present, but stopping it from running and scanning everything automatically.

You can read more about `upstart` and its configuration here:

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/

Since you're on the same version as me, I suspect this solution will work for you as it did for me.

Comment: I made it non executable